# Supervisord monitor in frontend Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, supervisord

Is it possible to replicate the same functionalities written in php [here in this repo](https://github.com/mlazarov/supervisord-monitor) with pure javascript HTTP requests? Since [Supervisord provides XML-RPC APIs](http://supervisord.org/api.html), and XML-RPC requests are basically POST calls.

I think my root problem is that I'm not entirely clear what backend can do that frontend can't. Is this one of those cases?

Comment: If it's truly HTTP Post, then it should be, as long as your calling system is able to properly negotiate potential CORS issues. Also, I note that someone has already started work on this: https://github.com/crcn-archive/node-supervisord, but I'm not sure whether it's accomplishing what you're after.

Comment: @Palpatim Node is still backend right? Basically I was asked to do this purely frontend, so I don't think Node would help. Right now I just want to know if this is even accomplishable in pure frontend.

Comment: @Luxiyalu php is server side, so any logic // database // 'work' will need to be done on a server. 

The client side can make calls to the back-end server to receive data, but nothing is persisted between clients and or server<-> client without the server side. 

Anything done on the client side, can't be guaranteed to persist, or do anything outside the machine it's running on! :)

Comment: @Pogrindis that makes sense. But then again, if I want a page like [this](https://github.com/mlazarov/supervisord-monitor) I don't really need to store any of these values, just request and display them. Is there a specific reason why these work-with-supervisord monitors are all written in backend languages?

Comment: Because where would you get the information from if you have no server side connection to query ? — You might want to consider a RESTFUL API ... This will separate the two, but you will still need the API running server side.

Comment: @Pogrindis But I already have a server which runs supervisord, and now I only need a display page somewhere else. Does this display page need to be a server too?

Comment: @Luxiyalu absolutely not, if the server can return info through a WEB REQUEST, you can make the call anywhere (allowing for cross domain issues etc but that's seperate). Look into javascript XHR requests || AJAX. This will allow you to make a HTTP Request to retrieve data from the supervisord. I will look into if supervisord have a built in API of sorts.

Comment: This might be useful, but I have not tested : https://github.com/timheap/jquery-xmlrpc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92413/discussion-between-luxiyalu-and-pogrindis).